# UPPAAL: Checking member of array

Tags: model-checking, uppaal

Is it possible to check if an object is element of an array in UPPAAL?

If I have a integer array

```
int ap[1,2];
```

I want to do a query in the verifier, where I have something like:

```
E<> 1 \in Process.ap[1]
```

And additionally, are there String types or character types in UPPAAL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no text strings in Uppaal.

Comment: oke, that's sad but ok :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `exists` expression.

Here is an example:

```
const int size=5;
typedef int[0,size-1] range_t;
typedef int set_t[range_t];

bool contains(const set_t& s, int el)
{
  return exists(i:range_t) s[i]==el;
}
```

Comment: I saw the custom user functions only used in the _update_ part of a transition. Is it also possible to use them in a query? If yes, can you describe how? :) Sorry for the lot of questions

Comment: Yes they can, they must be side-effect-free, e.g. pass by value or const reference.

Comment: I used your example code to have a contains method, but I always get syntax errors when using them in a Query. Here is a example:

`E<> P0.a and contains({1},1)`
unexpected '{', expecting ')' ... 

I placed the _contains_ method in the standard Project > Declarations path. What am I missing? 

Do I have to use other syntax for the set_t type?

Comment: Uppaal does not accept in-place constructions. A workaround is to create "const set_t one = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};" and then use "one" in the query.